# FFmpeg mix audio clips at given time into a main audio file

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

I has been recording small audio clips for an audio book. I have the start time of each one in seconds. The music lenght is of, let's say 60 min. I am thinking in create a silence audio file of the same duration as the music, but how I can add each clip into the given start time ? No matter if the clips overlap. I tried using concat and inpoint without the blank file and the output is empty (I am using wav files), that why the idea of use a master blank file as base.

If possible I would really appreciate any example.

Thanks

Comment: Adapt the answer at https://superuser.com/a/1092346/

Comment: That's a nice approach but... What if you have 100 clips?  Is possible to read the files from a txt like in concat?

Comment: Not with amix. concat demuxer can be used if the files don't overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope to understand your question. To create a silent wav file:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -t 01:00:00 silence.wav
```

Replace 01:00:00 (one hour) with the duration you need. Then, concat and mix the audio files. In this example, I use two small audio clip:

```
ffmpeg -i silence.wav -i clip1.wav -i clip2.wav -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=10[s1];aevalsrc=0:d=20[s2];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];[s2][2:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac2];[0:a][ac1][ac2]amix=3[aout]" -map [aout] out.wav
```

It's a very long command to mix lots of clips. So, try the bash script below. Instructions:

1. Copy the code below in a empty sh file, called mixing.sh
2. Replace "positions" with the instants in seconds to trigger each clip (my start time clips are 10, 22 and 35 seconds).
3. Make sure that all clips are placed in a folder called "clips" (next to .sh file). Remember to number the files (1.wav, 2.wav...)
4. Open a terminal and type: bash mixing.sh
5. The file out.wav must contain the audio clips at the desired positions.

Here the script, good luck!

```
#!/bin/bash

positions=(10 22 35)
seconds_at_the_end=2

clips_folder="./clips/"
filetype=".mp3"
silence_file="silence"$filetype
output_file="out"$filetype

command="ffmpeg"
file_id=1

aevalsrc=""
concat=""
mix="[0:a]"

clips=($clips_folder*$filetype)

last_clip_length=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ${clips[-1]} | awk '{printf("%d\n",$1 + 0.5)}')
silence_length=$((${positions[-1]}+last_clip_length+seconds_at_the_end))

eval $(ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -t $silence_length $silence_file)

for filename in $clips_folder*$filetype;
do
  inputs=$inputs" -i "$filename
  aevalsrc=$aevalsrc"aevalsrc=0:d=${positions[$((file_id-1))]}[s"$file_id"];"
  concat=$concat"[s"$file_id"]["$file_id":a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac"$file_id"];"
  mix=$mix"[ac"$file_id"]"
  file_id=$((file_id+1))
done

mix=$mix"amix="$((${#positions[*]}+1))"[aout]"

eval $($command -i $silence_file $inputs -filter_complex "$aevalsrc$concat$mix" -map [aout] $output_file)
```

Tip: I prefer free formats, like ogg (vorbis) or flac, it's more comfortable format to edit or transform. You can perform more complex operations and you are free to use. More info: https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Ogg_Vorbis

Comment: Thanks for that awesome answer.

Comment: Thinking in reaources, would not be better to have a pre created silent file of 2 hours by example, and then crop the lenght somehow to avoid to create it each time for different music track lenghts?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I think it's better create one with the precise duration. I improve my code to achive this. Now, the script creates the silence file. I have renamed "durations" variable to "positions".

Comment: You can get just the duration directly from `ffprobe` and eliminate `sed`. See [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604)

Comment: Hey we can reduce the load by just skip the silent file creation, instead have a base file of 4 hours and use the flag -t duration at the end of the mix outout

Comment: I got this error: `zsh: no matches found: [aout]`